# Swiper.js content text spills into next slide + Slide repeats when you go prev

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I am trying to use Swiper for this portfolio project. The problem with the front-end of this site is that the content text spills into next slide. The content should stay within its slide. The problem with the back-end of my program is that the slide repeats when the swiper-button-prev is pressed up to 3x and then the swiper resets to the first image.

It was working fine but I don't know what I messed up.

[image: Contect spilling out into next slide]

HTML Projects Section:

```
<!-- Include Swiper CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<!--==================== PROJECTS ====================-->
<section class="projects section" id="projects">
<div class="title__container">
    <h2 class="section__title">Projects</h2>
    <span class="section__subtitle">My recent works</span>
</div>

<div class="container grid section__border">
    <!--==================== PROJECTS 1 ====================-->

    <h3 class="qualification__title">
        Software Development
    </h3>
    <div class="projects__container swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Project 1 -->
            <div class="projects__content swiper-slide">
                <img src="assets/img/project1.jpg" alt="Project 1" class="projects__img">
                <h3 class="projects__title">Number Guesser</h3>
                <p class="projects__description">A simple number-guessing game where you compete against the computer to guess the target number. This project is implemented using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
                </p>
                <a href="https://github.com/neesssam/Number-Guesser" class="button button--flex button--small projects__button">
                    Demo
                    <i class="ri-arrow-right-line button__icon"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Project 2 -->
            <div class="projects__content swiper-slide">
                <img src="assets/img/project2.jpg" alt="Project 2" class="projects__img">
                <h3 class="projects__title">Lottery Simulation Program</h3>
                <p class="projects__description">Simple simulation of a lottery game written in C++. Can be used as a starting point for more complex lottery simulations.</p>
                 <p class="projects__description">
                <a href="https://github.com/neesssam/Lottery-Simulation-Program" class="button button--flex button--small projects__button">
                    Demo
                    <i class="ri-arrow-right-line button__icon"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Project 3 -->
            <div class="projects__content swiper-slide">
                <img src="assets/img/project3.jpg" alt="Project 3" class="projects__img">
                <h3 class="projects__title">REST API for E-Commerce Platform</h3>
                <p class="projects__description">[This Project is Under Construction]</p>
                <a href="#" class="button button--flex button--small projects__button">
                    Demo
                    <i class="ri-arrow-right-line button__icon"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Add Projects Pagination -->
        <div class="projects-swiper-pagination swiper-pagination"></div>

        <!-- Projects Swiper Navigation -->
        <div class="projects-swiper-button-next swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="projects-swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>

    <!--==================== PROJECTS 2 ====================-->

        <h3 class="qualification__title">
            UI/UX Design [Under Construction]
        </h3>
        <div class="projects__container swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Project 1 -->
                <div class="projects__content swiper-slide">
                    <img src="assets/img/project1.jpg" alt="Project 1" class="projects__img">
                    <h3 class="projects__title">Oops!</h3>
                    <p class="projects__description">These fields are empty... for now.
                    </p>
                    <a href="https://github.com/neesssam/Number-Guesser" class="button button--flex button--small projects__button">
                        Demo
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-line button__icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
    
                <!-- Project 2 -->
                <div class="projects__content swiper-slide">
                    <img src="assets/img/project2.jpg" alt="Project 2" class="projects__img">
                    <h3 class="projects__title">Oops!</h3>
                    <p class="projects__description">These fields are empty... for now.</p>
                    <a href="https://github.com/neesssam/Lottery-Simulation-Program" class="button button--flex button--small projects__button">
                        Demo
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-line button__icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
    
                <!-- Project 3 -->
                <div class="projects__content swiper-slide">
                    <img src="assets/img/project3.jpg" alt="Project 3" class="projects__img">
                    <h3 class="projects__title">Oops!</h3>
                    <p class="projects__description">These fields are empty... for now.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button button--flex button--small projects__button">
                        Demo
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-line button__icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Add Projects Pagination -->
            <div class="projects-swiper-pagination swiper-pagination"></div>
    
            <!-- Projects Swiper Navigation -->
            <div class="projects-swiper-button-next swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="projects-swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Include Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Software Dev Swiper --> 
<script>
  var swiperProjects1 = new Swiper(".projects__container", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    slidesPerGroup: 3,
    loop: true,
    loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
});
</script>

<!-- UI/UX Swiper --> <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var swiperProjects2 = new Swiper('.projects__container', {
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.projects-swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.projects-swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.projects-swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

Main.js

```
/*=============== SWIPER PROJECTS ===============*/

let swiperProjects = new Swiper(".projects__container", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 24,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.projects-swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.projects-swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.projects-swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  breakpoints: {
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: -56,
    },
  },
});
```

Projects CSS

```
/*=============== PROJECTS ===============*/

.projects__content {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.projects__content h3, p, a{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.projects__img {
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0 auto 1.25rem;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.projects__subtitle {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  color: var(--text-color-light);
}

.projects__title {
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
}

.projects__button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
}

.projects__button i {
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.projects__button:hover i {
  transform: translateX(0.25rem);
}

.swiper-button-prev::after,
.swiper-button-next::after {
  content: '';
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  width: initial;
  height: initial;
  margin: initial;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  top: 4.5rem;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  top: 4.5rem;
}

.projects__container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 3rem; /* Add left padding to create space for the arrows */
  padding-right: 3rem; /* Add right padding to create space for the arrows */
}

.projects__container .swiper-button-prev,
.projects__container .swiper-button-next {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--title-color);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 10;
}

.projects__container .swiper-button-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.projects__container .swiper-button-next {
  right: 0;
}


.projects__container .swiper-slide {
  margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
}

.projects__container .swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: 0;
}

.projects__container .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background-color: var(--text-color-light);
  opacity: initial;
}

.projects__container .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: var(--title-color);
}
```

Breakpoints CSS

```
/*=============== BREAKPOINTS ===============*/
/* For small devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 340px){
  .container{
    margin-inline: 1rem;
  }

  .nav_list{
    gap: 1rem 1.25rem;
  }

  .skills__info{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  }

  .projects__img{
    width: 200px;
    justify-self: center;
  }

  .projects__container{
    width: 400px;
  }

  .projects__container{
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .projects__container .swiper-button-prev {
    left: 0;
  }

  .projects__container .swiper-button-next {
    right: 0;
  }
 
}

/* For medium devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 576px){
  .nav,
  .nav__menu{
    width: 380px;
  }
  .nav{
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .skills__container{
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .projects__container{
    width: 400px;
  }

  .projects__container{
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .projects__container .swiper-button-prev {
    left: 0;
  }

  .projects__container .swiper-button-next {
    right: 0;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px){
  .home__container{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  }

  .home__data{
    order: 2;
  }

  .home__info:nth-child(3){
    order: 3;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .home__info{
    margin-top:0;
  }

  .home__info-description{
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  .skills__container,
  .qualification__container,
  .services__container{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, max-content);
  }

  .skills__container,
  .services__container{
    column-gap: 5rem;
  }
  .qualification__container{
    column-gap: 10rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    padding: 3rem;
  }

  .projects__container{
    width: 500px;
  }
}

/* For large devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px){
  .header{
    top:0;
    bottom: initial;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    transition: .4s;
  }

  .nav{
    width: initial;
    height: calc(var(--header-height+ 1.5rem));
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    column-gap: 3rem;
    margin-inline: 1.5rem;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .nav__link i,
  .nav__toggle,
  .nav__close{
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__menu{
    width: initial;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    transition: background .4s;
  }
  .nav__list{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 3rem;
  }
  .nav__link{
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  }
  .dark-theme .nav,
  .dark-theme .nav__menu{
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .change-theme{
    color: var(--text-color-light);
  }
  .change-theme:hover{
    color: var(--title-color);
  }

  .section{
    padding-block: 8rem 0;
  }
  .home__title{
    font-size: 2.25rem;
  }
  .scrollup{
    right: 3rem;
  }
  .show-scroll{
    bottom: 5rem;
  }

  /* Change background header */
  .bg-header{
    box-shadow: 0 4px 20px hsla(207,24%,35%,.1);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1048px) {
  .container{
    margin-inline: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
  .section__border{
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
  }
  .section__subtitle{
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .home__title{
    font-size: var(--biggest-font-size);
  }
  .home__blob{
    width: 400px;
    height: 580px;
    border-radius: 12.5rem;
  }
  .home__perfil{
    width: 340px;
    height: 520px;
    border-radius: 10.6rem;
  }
  .home__perfil img{
    width: 300px;
  }
  .home__shape-waves{
    width: 100px;
    left: -4rem;
    top: 10rem;
  }
  .home__shape-circle{
    width: 250px;
    bottom: -1rem;
    right: -5rem;
  }
  .home__data{
    row-gap: 2.5rem;
  }
  .home__social{
    column-gap:2rem;
  }
  .home__social-link{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .home__info{
   display: grid;
   row-gap: 2rem;
  }

  .skills__container{
    column-gap: 10rem;
  }
  
  .skills__title i{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
  .skills__name{
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  }
  .skills__info{
    gap: 3rem;
  }

  .qualification__container{
    column-gap: 14rem;
  }
  .qualification__title{
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }
  .qualification__title i{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
  .qualification__name{
    font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  }
  .qualification__img{
    width: 300px;
    left: -6rem;
    bottom: 5rem;
  }

  .services__container{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
  }

  .services__card{
    width: 245px;
    height: 345px;
    border-radius: 7.6rem;
    padding: 3.5rem 1.5rem;
  }
  .services__card i{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .services__border{
    width: 265px;
    height: 365px;
    border-radius: 8.25rem;
  }

  .projects__container{
    width: 900px;
  }
  .projects__container{
    width: 900px;
  }
  .projects__container .swiper-button-prev,
  .projects__container .swiper-button-next{
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .projects__container .swiper-button-prev{
    left: 0;
  }
  .projects__container .swiper-button-next{
    right: 0;
  }
  .projects__container .swiper-button-next{
    margin-bottom: 6.5rem;
  }
  .projects__img{
    width: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  

  .contact__title{
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }
  .contact__title i{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }
  .contact__info{
    row-gap: 3rem;
  }
  .contact__data-info{
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  }
  .contact__form{
    row-gap: 2.5rem;
  }

  .footer__container{
    padding: 4rem 0 3rem;
  }
  .footer__list{
    column-gap: 3rem;
    margin: 3rem 0;
  }
  .footer__social{
    column-gap: 2rem;
  }
  .footer__social-link{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .footer__copy{
    margin-top: 5rem;
  }
}
/* For small devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .projects__container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: unset;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  
  .projects__container .swiper-button-prev,
  .projects__container .swiper-button-next{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--title-color);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .projects__container .swiper-button-prev {
    left: 1rem; /* Adjust the left position */
    right: auto; /* Reset the right position */
  }

  .projects__container .swiper-button-next {
    right: 1rem; /* Adjust the right position */
    left: auto; /* Reset the left position */
  }

}
```

I tried to limit the width of the content, align it, position it, and tried to go back and see what I changed with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your code you are assigning 2 different swiper instances to the same class ".projects__container". you need to separate the two swiper instances with separate classes and that should fix the swiping functionality.

I renamed them to "swiper-project1" and "swiper-project2"

```
<!-- Software Dev Swiper --> 
<script>
  let swiperProjects = new Swiper(".swiper-project1", {
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 24,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.projects-swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.projects-swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.projects-swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    breakpoints: {
      1200: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: -56,
      },
    },
  });
</script>

<!-- UI/UX Swiper --> 
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var swiperProjects2 = new Swiper('.swiper-project2', {
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.projects-swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.projects-swiper-button-prev',
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.projects-swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
  });
});
</script>
```

keep the "projects__container" class in both of the swiper `<div>` elements and add the relative "swiper-project1" & "swiper-project2" like so:

```
<div class="projects__container swiper-project1 swiper-container">
    <!-- your code -->
</div>


<div class="projects__container swiper-project2 swiper-container">
    <!-- your code -->
</div>
```